# Excel sheet size/scrollbar resizing issue when going too far down a sheet

Tags: excel, resize, spreadsheet

So I've run into this issue for years but it's not systematic in how I operate. It really only happens on the occasional screw up of a macro, or mistyping of keys, or something of that sort.

If I hit Ctrl+down in a blank spreadsheet and input a value in the 1048576th row, then delete/clear that cell and hit Ctrl+up, the sheet will not resize and think that the size of the sheet is still as big as the 1048576th row. It is indicated by the fact that the scroll button is so small and covers a great distance of rows when moved. I can then select the whole range of the sheet and delete, and it still thinks the size of the sheet is that big.

How do I resize the sheet if deleting all the rows does not work? [I would like to avoid creating a new sheet like this guy suggests.](http://www.electronmedia.in/wp/fix-excel2010-large-file-sizescrollbar-issues/)

Comment: After deleting, did you try closing and reopening the workbook?

Comment: @ScottCraner So it works on my test sheet that I created from a blank sheet just as I described in the post. The existing workbook that I actually have the issue with doesn't seem to be receptive when I delete all rows below the 20th that I need, then save and reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the workbook after deleting rows and the slider will resize to normal. Took me a while to figure that one out:)

Comment: As I stated in one of the comments, it works on my test sheet that I created from a blank sheet just as I described in the post. The existing workbook that I actually have the issue with doesn't seem to be receptive when I delete all rows below the 20th that I need, then save and reopen

Comment: Hm, that is weird. You can try making a new sheet and copying only the 20 rows you need into it, then deleting the old sheet. If the problem continues, you could put this procedure into your VBA code, at the end.